# How to use two different React versions in a monorepo with Turborepo and avoid conflicts?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-dom, monorepo

I'm creating a monorepo using Turborepo and have two applications in my apps folder: app-x, which uses "react": "17.0.2", and app-y, which uses "react": "18.0.2". Additionally, I have a separate ui package component which uses react 17.0.2 as a dev dependency.

After running my app, I encountered some kind of React version conflict. I tried setting up resolutions in the root package.json file, and all the errors disappeared. However, after running app-x again, it seemed to be using React version 18.0.2.

I've been searching online for a solution, but I haven't found a proper one for my case. How can I use two different React/React DOM versions in my monorepo without causing a mess in my applications? I simply want app-x to use React version 17.0.2 and app-y to use React version 18.0.2. Any hints will be appreciated.

```js
  
  //root package.json
  
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "<17.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "<17.0.6",
    "react": "17.0.2 || 18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2 || 18.2.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "app-x": {
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2"
    },
    "app-y": {
        "react": "18.0.2",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?